# Instead of running the query individually for all parameters, how can I run the query collectively?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-string

I have vendorIDs that are planned to be merged.

I'm using the following query to find the total number of orders (PO) they contain. In this way, I will start the process with those with a high order (PO).

But instead of running the query individually for all rows, how can I run the query collectively for the remaining blank rows?

(my aim is to fill the yellow marked fields easily because there are 158 lines, I don't want to copy,paste 158 times for 158 lines)

```sql
select count(distinct P.PONo)
from scm.dbo.PODetailReport P
JOIN EGAA.dbo.users U On U.ID=p.ORIGINATORUSERID
Where u.IsDisabled=0
and 
P.VendorID in 
(
50,66674
)
```

[Click for excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwS1w.png)

I tried using union all but it failed when executed in sql

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL, which are you really using? SQL Server 2008 has also been *completely* unsupported for well over 3 years, so you *really* need to complete your upgrade path, is that is the product you are using.

Comment: The fact that your table references is `EGAA.dbo.users` suggests that you are using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL. What does `SELECT @@version;` return?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
select P.VendorID, count(distinct P.PONo)
from scm.dbo.PODetailReport P
JOIN EGAA.dbo.users U On U.ID=p.ORIGINATORUSERID
Where u.IsDisabled=0
and 
P.VendorID in 
(
50,66674
)
group by P.VendorID
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but no :( I am looking for a way to search for different vendor ID groups in P.VendorID at once. (because i have different vendor id groups and i don't want to paste these groups in where clause one by one.)